# Visual Studio Tab out of brackets/quotes?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm primarily a Java developer and I've recently started developing apps for Windows Store using Visual Studio 2012. When I started coding several years ago, I used Visual Studio 2008. I didn't think anything of certain features until I started doing Java in Eclipse. Anyway, in Eclipse, I can press "tab" to jump out of quotes or brackets. The only Visual Studio 2012 feature I could find remotely similar to this was included in [Visual Studio 2012 Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3a96a4dc-ba9c-4589-92c5-640e07332afd). It allows me to do Shift+Enter anywhere on a line, and it'll add a semicolon to the end of the line and go to the next one. While this is useful, it's not ideal in many situations. I am also using Resharper and have found no such setting in there. Thanks

Comment: I've added this issue to add that behavior in ReSharper; I miss it as well: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-395322

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to jump out of the automatically inserted quote or bracket is to type the closing quote or bracket, i.e.: `"` followed by `"` or `(` followed by `)`. You could also use the right arrow key. If you have resharper then you can use `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` to auto complete the current statement.

If you are a fan of keyboard shortcuts to move around your code then try the [VsVim Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329).

Comment: On mac it just inserts another " when I try to close it, so annoying